# Error building Player: Currently selected scripting backend (Mono) is not installed

Tags: c#, unity3d, mono

Unity.

Проблема возникла из ниоткуда

вот полное [image: #]

Comment: Ну так установите

Comment: @aepot, гений, его нельзя установить, он идет сразу в комплекте с Unity! Это среда .NET!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать новый проект и перенести папку Assets (старого проекта) в новый проект.

(это баг похоже)